# Prove continuity of $f$ given that $-\pi < f(t) < \pi$ and two continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**The Problem**

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a funciton and that both of the functions

$$
l(t) = \cos(f(t)) \mbox{ and } m(t)=\sin(f(t))
$$

are continuous.

Prove that if $-\pi < f(t) < \pi$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is continuous.

**Attempt**

It is clear that if we don't have the upper and lower bounds on $f$ the statement fails, for example we can take

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{if } t=0 \\
\pi &\mbox{if } t\not=0.
\end{cases}
$$
And then we would have that $l(t)\equiv 1$ and $m(t) \equiv 0$ being trivially continuous while $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $t=0$.

So basically a direct proof seems like an nightmare. I'm willing to bet this will be a proof by contradiction. However, the epsilon delta characterization of not being continuous at a point doesn't seem to help either.

**Request**

I'm mainly just looking for a starting point, no need to provide a full solution. If I go the contradiction route, Is it possible to avoid doing cases with different types of discontinuities?

Comment: Maybe take the point of discontinuity on $f$ and prove $l$ and $m$ can't be continuous at that point

Comment: a quick solution using complex analysis is that $h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C, h(t)=e^{if(t)}$ is continuous and has the image away from the negative axis since $|h(t)|=1, \cos f(t) \ne -1$ (so $h(t) \ne -1)$; but then the principal branch of the logarithm is defined continuously on its image and we recover $f=\log h/i$ so $f$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

Hint for one method: let $S$ be the unit circle in $\Bbb R^2$, define $g\colon \Bbb R\to S\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ by $g(t) = \bigl( l(t),m(t) \bigr)$, and let $h\colon S\setminus\{(-1,0)\} \to (-\pi,\pi)$ be the map that sends a point to its angle with the $x$-axis. What can you say about the continuity of various compositions of these maps?